# Quasar + Docker not working on localhost, but works with given external IP

Tags: laravel, docker, nginx, docker-compose, quasar-framework

I'm trying to dockerize a stack with nginx + Quasar + Laravel + Mysql.
Since I'm using 3th party plugins that need approved domains I'd like to be always using localhost instead of dynamic public IPs.

I've tried everything, but since I'm starting with docker there are many concepts that I may be not understanding.

This is probably related to port forwarding, but the problem is that I can't access Quasar app by using `http://localhost:9000/`

This is my docker-compose.yml

```yaml
version: '3.8'
services:
  # Laravel App
  api:
    build:
      args:
        user: luciano
        uid: 1000
      context: backend        # path to the docker file
      dockerfile: Dockerfile  # name of the dockerfile
    image: laravel            # name to assign to the image
    container_name: viso-api  # name to assign to the container
    restart: unless-stopped   # always restart container except when stopped (manually or otherwise)
    working_dir: /var/www     # working directory of the running container
    tty: true                 # once started keeps container running (attaching a terminal to it, like using -t docker directive)
    environment:              # set environment variables
      SERVICE_NAME: app
      SERVICE_TAGS: dev
    depends_on:
      - db
    volumes:                  # map application directory in the /var/www/html directory of the container
      - './backend:/var/www'
      - './.docker/php/uploads.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/uploads.ini'
    networks:                 # networks at which container is connected
      - viso-network

  # Quasar App
  quasar:
    build:
      context: frontend
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
      target: develop-stage
    image: quasar
    container_name: viso-frontend
    working_dir: /app
    volumes:
      - './frontend:/app'
    networks:
      - viso-network
    depends_on:
      - api
    # command: /bin/sh -c "yarn && quasar dev"

  # Nginx Service
  nginx:
    image: 'nginx:1.23.1-alpine'
    container_name: viso-nginx
    restart: unless-stopped
    tty: true
    ports:                    # exposed ports
      - '8888:80'
    volumes:
      - './backend:/var/www'
      - './.docker/nginx:/etc/nginx/conf.d' # nginx configuration
    networks:
      - viso-network
    depends_on:
      - db
      - api

  # MySQL Service
  db:
    image: 'mysql:8.0.30'
    container_name: viso-db
    restart: unless-stopped
    tty: true
    ports:
      - '33066:3306'
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: viso_manager
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: secretroot
      MYSQL_ROOT_HOST: '%'
      MYSQL_USER: luciano
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: secretluciano
    volumes:
      - './.dbdata:/var/lib/mysql'
      - './.docker/mysql/my.cnf:/etc/mysql/conf.d/my.cnf'
    networks:
      - viso-network

# Docker Networks
networks:
  viso-network:
    driver: bridge

# Volumes
volumes:
  .dbdata:
```

This is my Laravel Dockerfile:

```yaml
FROM php:8.1-fpm

# Set working directory
WORKDIR /var/www

# Get argument defined in docker-compose file
ARG user
ARG uid

# Install system dependencies
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    git \
    curl \
    libonig-dev \
    libxml2-dev \
    libpng-dev \
    libwebp-dev \
    libjpeg-dev \
    libfreetype6-dev \
    zip \
    unzip \
    nano \
    && docker-php-ext-install pdo_mysql \
    && docker-php-ext-install mbstring \
    && docker-php-ext-install exif \
    && docker-php-ext-install pcntl \
    && docker-php-ext-install bcmath \
    && docker-php-ext-install gd \
    && docker-php-ext-configure gd --with-jpeg --with-webp --with-freetype \
    && docker-php-ext-install -j$(nproc) gd \
    && docker-php-source delete

# Clear cache
RUN apt-get clean && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# Install Composer
RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer

# Create system user to run Composer and Artisan Commands
RUN useradd -G www-data,root -u $uid -d /home/$user $user
RUN mkdir -p /home/$user/.composer && \
    chown -R $user:$user /home/$user

EXPOSE 80
USER $user
```

This is my Quasar Dockerfile

```yaml
# develop stage
FROM node:alpine as develop-stage
WORKDIR /app
COPY package*.json ./
RUN yarn global add @quasar/cli
COPY . .
RUN yarn install
EXPOSE 9999

# build stage
FROM develop-stage as build-stage
RUN yarn
RUN quasar build

# production stage
FROM nginx:alpine as production-stage
COPY --from=build-stage /app/dist/spa /usr/share/nginx/html
EXPOSE 80
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

and my nginx.conf

```
server {
    listen 80;
    index index.php index.html;
    error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    root /var/www/public;
    client_max_body_size 32M;
    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass api:9000;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
    }
    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
        gzip_static on;
    }
    location /storage {
        add_header "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" "*";
    }
}
```

Once everything is up and running, I go into Quasar container and run `quasar dev` which shows me 2 URLs

```
App URL................ http://localhost:9000/
                        http://172.xx.xx.4:9000/
```

The url by IP works fine, but `http://localhost:9000/` throws

```
This site can’t be reached
localhost refused to connect.
Try:

Checking the connection
Checking the proxy and the firewall
ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
```

Comment: Are you sure that your ```hosts``` file is correct?

Comment: how exactly do you access these URLs? From within the container? With what (`curl`?).